# assigning itertools combinations output to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to assign the output of itertools combinations function to a numpy array and it is creating a blank array.
Why does this code not work correctly?

```
    import numpy as np
    from itertools import combinations

    A=[10,5,7,90,4,200,64]
    B=combinations(A,5)
    NA=np.zeros([5,21],dtype=np.uint8)

    print (list(B))

    NA=list(B)
    print (NA)
```

Comment: `B` is a generator once exhausted, you can't iterrate again. `list(B)` will consume whole generator

Comment: `B` is a generator, which can be used only once.  The 2nd `list(B)` operates on a used, empty generator.  Also that first `NA=...` assignment does nothing for you; the 2nd overwrites it.  `NA = np.array(list(combinations(A,5)))` is all you need.  (along with some more basic Python study :)  ).

Answer (score 1):

Save the output of generator B when you exhaust it in order to use it later:

```
A=[10,5,7,90,4,200,64]
B=combinations(A,5)
#this is line is not really required unless you use it in between your lines here
NA=np.zeros([5,21],dtype=np.uint8)

B=list(B)
print(B)

NA=np.array(B)
print (NA)
```